# OpenMP memory leaks?

Tags: c, openmp, matrix-multiplication

I have been trying to parallelize divide and conquer matrix multiplication using OpenMP. The code works perfectly fine till 512 x 512 matrices but gives bus error when I give an input of 1024 x 1024 matrix.
I ran valgrind for a small input - 128 x 128 matrix but saw that there are memory leaks.

```
==3864== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3864==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3864==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3864==      possibly lost: 2,016 bytes in 7 blocks
==3864==    still reachable: 3,088 bytes in 4 blocks
==3864==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3864== 
==3864== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3864== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

However, when I run it removing the the fopenmp compiler option, I don't get any valgrind error!

```
==4186== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4186==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4186==   total heap usage: 12,982,328 allocs, 12,982,328 frees, 139,548,672 bytes allocated
==4186== 
==4186== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4186== 
==4186== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4186== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Here is the snippet of the recursive multiply function I wrote.
Is there anything wrong with the way I am using OpenMP? - full code here https://pastebin.com/Wdqmu045
Thank You.

```
    #pragma omp parallel sections  
    {
        #pragma omp section  
        {     
            x1=multiply(a11,b11,m);
        }
        #pragma omp section  
        {     
            x2=multiply(a12,b21,m);
        }
        #pragma omp section  
        {     
            x3=multiply(a11,b12,m);
        }
        #pragma omp section  
        {       
            x4=multiply(a12,b22,m);
        }
        #pragma omp section  
        {     
            x5=multiply(a21,b11,m);
        }
        #pragma omp section  
        {     
            x6=multiply(a22,b21,m);
        }
        #pragma omp section  
        {     
            x7=multiply(a21,b12,m);
        }
        #pragma omp section  
        {     
            x8=multiply(a22,b22,m);
        }
    }
```

Comment: BTW the first thing you should do in order to debug the bus error, is to check the return codes of all `malloc` calls. Dynamically allocating memory over and over in a parallel application is a very bad idea in terms of performance, as `malloc` usually implies some sort of synchronization.

Comment: I do agree, but I don't know how to reduce the malloc calls.